# How to combine a sales forecast, planned deliveries, and current inventory to project future inventory using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, forecasting

I have three data sources:

Sales Forecast - This is future forecasted sales for products:

| Product | Forecast_Quantity | Forecast_Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 5 | 2021-02-28 |
| Product B | 6 | 2021-02-28 |
| Product C | 2 | 2021-02-28 |
| Product A | 5 | 2021-03-31 |
| Product B | 6 | 2021-03-31 |
| Product C | 2 | 2021-03-31 |
| Product A | 5 | 2021-04-30 |
| Product B | 6 | 2021-04-30 |
| Product C | 2 | 2021-04-30 |

Planned Deliveries (Purchase Orders) - what is planned to be delivered in:

| Product | Delivery_Quantity | Delivery_Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 2 | 2021-02-28 |
| Product B | 4 | 2021-02-28 |
| Product C | 5 | 2021-02-28 |
| Product A | 8 | 2021-03-31 |
| Product B | 2 | 2021-03-31 |
| Product C | 4 | 2021-03-31 |
| Product A | 2 | 2021-04-30 |
| Product B | 6 | 2021-04-30 |
| Product C | 3 | 2021-04-30 |

Current inventory - what is currently in stock:

| Product | Inventory_Quantity | Inventory_Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 20 | 2021-01-31 |
| Product B | 16 | 2021-01-31 |
| Product C | 21 | 2021-01-31 |

I wish to create a small program that returns a dataframe projecting my future inventory for each product. It should take last months closing inventory add on the delivery quantity and take off the forecasted sales.
Expected output:

| Product | Inventory_Quantity | Inventory_Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 20 | 2021-01-31 |
| Product B | 16 | 2021-01-31 |
| Product C | 21 | 2021-01-31 |
| Product A | 17 | 2021-02-28 |
| Product B | 14 | 2021-02-28 |
| Product C | 24 | 2021-02-28 |

It would be for 18 months of data (but I've just used a 2 months of output for the above table).

I've have tried a few different approaches, such as trying `cusum()` or using a `for` loop but I don't my logic has been right.

This is the code I have so far that combines the forecast and deliveries into a 'net' figure:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Import CSV files as dataframe
fcs = pd.read_csv(r'forecast.csv')
inv = pd.read_csv(r'inventory.csv')
pos = pd.read_csv(r'purchase_orders.csv')

# Inner join to get a net position for each month (PO Qty - Fcs Qty)
net = pd.merge(pos, fcs, left_on=['SKU', 'Delivery_Date'], right_on=['SKU', 'Forecast_Date'])

# Create net
net['net'] = (net['PO_Quantity'] - net['Forecast_Quantity'])
```

I'm unsure on the best approach to now generate the new table that combines with the inventory?

Comment: B and C don't add up for me. Can you double-check the math? Or can you explain it for AB or C?

Comment: @DavidErickson sorry B was wrong but other 2 should be correct. So C starts at 21 - 2 forecast + 5 delivery = 24 total stock for Feb 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat` to vertically combine the three dataframes. Then, `fillna` the inventory columns with the others and `melt` the dataframe. From there, you can take the `cumsum`:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1.assign(Forecast_Quantity=df1['Forecast_Quantity'] * -1)
                    .rename({'Forecast_Month' : 'Inventory_Month', 
                            'Forecast_Quantity' : 'Inventory_Quantity'}, axis=1),
                 df2.rename({'Delivery_Month' : 'Inventory_Month', 
                            'Delivery_Quantity' : 'Inventory_Quantity'}, axis=1),
                 df3]).sort_values(['Product', 'Inventory_Month']))
df['Inventory_Quantity'] = df.groupby('Product')['Inventory_Quantity'].cumsum()
df = (df.groupby(['Product', 'Inventory_Month'], as_index=False).last()
        .sort_values('Inventory_Month'))
df

Out[1]: 
      Product Inventory_Month  Inventory_Quantity
0   Product A      2021-01-31                20.0
4   Product B      2021-01-31                16.0
8   Product C      2021-01-31                21.0
1   Product A      2021-02-28                17.0
5   Product B      2021-02-28                14.0
9   Product C      2021-02-28                24.0
2   Product A      2021-03-31                20.0
6   Product B      2021-03-31                10.0
10  Product C      2021-03-31                26.0
3   Product A      2021-04-30                17.0
7   Product B      2021-04-30                10.0
11  Product C      2021-04-30                27.0
```

Comment: Hi @DavidErickson thanks for the response but this only works for the first month. It should take the new closing inventory from the previous month, your solution always takes the first inventory from df3. How would I get it to take last months inventory before netting the forecast and deliveries?

Comment: @Calum please try my updated answer. In future, kindly include the full expected output based on input (instead of only a portion of the rows). Thank you!

Comment: perfect! Solution works as required, sorry about my poorly formatted question. You've also introduced some new pandas concepts to me which I will go and research so I understand your method. Marking as solved.